# Naming Collection Extensions for clarity

Tags: java, generics, collections, coding-style

Introducing some of the goodness of collection operations to our codebase without adding a new external library dependency, we are adding these methods to our utility package.

```
static public List<T> filter(List<T> source, Predicate<T> filter);
static <Y,T> public List<Y> transform(List<T> source, Mutator<Y,T> filter);
static public boolean exists(List<T> source, Predicate<T> filter);
static public T findFirst(List<T> source, Predicate<T> filter);
static public boolean trueForAll(List<T> source, Predicate<T> filter);
```

With the attendant interfaces

```
public interface Predicate<T> { public boolean apply(T item); }
public interface Mutator<T,Y> { public Y apply(T item); }
```

So the questions:

- Is Filters a good name for the class containing the extensions? If not, a better?
- Is Mutator<T,Y> appropriately named?
- Should I prefer **map** to **transform** and **reduce** to **filter**?
- Are there any important set-based functions that I've forgotten to include in the library class?

**Edited to add**: A significant argument I have against **map** (and thus in favor of **transform**) is that **map** has significant semantic load due to the many uses for java.util.Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call them **map** and **filter**. Reduce has a slightly different meaning for me, and transform is too vague. As for the class name, Filters may not be the best, but I don't have a better recommendation.

I know you weren't asking for this specifically, but some of the signatures in the generic methods can be improved:

```
 static public <T> List<T> filter(List<T> source, Predicate<? super T> filter);
 static public <Y,T> List<Y> transform(List<T> source, Mutator<Y,? super T> filter);
 static public <T> boolean exists(List<T> source, Predicate<? super T> filter);
 static public <T> T findFirst(List<T> source, Predicate<? super T> filter);
 static public <T> boolean trueForAll(List<T> source, Predicate<? super T> filter);
```

Comment: Thanks, since I'm used to thinking in CLR generics rather than JDK5 generics, it's definitely a good point.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any important set-based
>   functions that I've forgotten to
>   include in the library class?

For higher-order collection functions I use the approach outlined by Adrian Kuhn in his article "[Pimp My Foreach](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~akuhn/blog/2008/pimp-my-foreach-loop/)".

Some of these you've already got, but thought I'd throw them out there anyway:

- AllSatisfy
- AnySatisfy
- Cardinality
- Collect
- Count
- CutPieces
- Detect
- Fold
- GroupedBy
- IndexOf
- Inject
- Reject
- Select

Answer (score 1):

This looks really nice; I think you're definitely on the right track here.  Yes, I think Mutator is a good name; transform is better because it's more commonly read as a verb, and map has a "noun" connotation that might be confusing; and the only major set-based function that I could think that you might want would be a reordering function.

Comment: since Collections.sort is available, I didn't think we needed an additional sorting method.

Answer (score 1):

in a similar library I used:

- **Specification** in place of **Predicate**: 
  `aSpecification.isSatisfiedBy(anObject);`
- **Mapper** in place of **Mutator**
- **map** is **collect** for smalltalkers (**transform** in your case)
- **fold** is **inject** for smalltalkers
- **filter** is **select** for smalltalkers

Comment: fold? what's the underlying operation there?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really what you asked, but it's in the spirit of your question.  To me, it reads better to say:

```
List<String> shortWords = filtered(allWords, short);
```

than

```
List<String> shortWords = filter(allWords, short);
```

I would stick with **transform** and **filter**.

Comment: I would tend to disagree; I think the verb works a little clearer than the adjective (because it more accurately describes the fact that some action is occurring).  It's a minor disagreement, though.

Comment: I tend to think of methods as actions. filter seems more appropriate  than filtered. The important thing is to be consistent though.

Comment: I can understand your reasoning, McWafflestix & ebrown, but I like to name a value-returning function so that it describes what is returned.  What is returned is the filtered list, it is not the filter.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem Transform should be Mutate (or alternatively Mutator should be Transformer,) for consistency's sake.   This seems fairly clear about the intent:

```
static <Y,T> public List<Y> mutate (List<T> originalForm, Mutator<Y,T> mutator);
```

It is also a bit more verbose (but more consistent and conventional) to spec:

```
static public boolean isTrueForAll(List<T> source, Predicate<T> filter);
```

or

```
static public boolean assertTrueForAll(List<T> source, Predicate<T> filter);
```

Comment: good point about isTrueForAll vs. trueForAll ... (but I have to admit coming at this from the "what's missing from JDK1.5 collections that is present in the .Net BCL" perspective, so my naming expectation had a preexisting bias...